# queria fazer um server transfer para a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

eu estou a tentar fazer um server transfer para a minha master page mas esta a dar este erro:

Não foi encontrado qualquer processador de HTTP para o tipo de pedido 'POST'
Descrição: Exceção não processada ao executar o pedido Web atual. Consulte o rastreio da pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e o respetivo ponto de origem no código.

o codigo que eu tenho e
na pagina aspx:

```
Context.Items["id"] = c.idCliente;
Server.Transfer("~/MasterPage.master");
```

master page:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Context.Items["id"]);
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode fazer um transporte ou redirecionamento para a `MasterPage.master`, ela não é uma página comum, mas sim um recurso para ser usado como template ao ser herdada por outras páginas. Você precisa criar uma nova página para servir de destino ao seu `Server.Transfer()`.